# Load course sections dynamically in moodle

Tags: dynamic, format, moodle, sections

I am trying to create a moodle course format just like moodle topics format which will dynamically load topics/sections and not all at once. I need some headstart for the same.I am trying to load course sections dynamically because I want to handle condition where there will be more than 100 course sections and loading those amount of sections on one go will cause session lock error for user.

I checked few course formats on moodle plugins directory for the same but could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

There is a contributed plugin called "Collapsed Topics"

The contents are hidden until the student clicks the drop down arrow to reveal the content

Download/details here

https://moodle.org/plugins/format_topcoll

Or see if there is a suitable course format here

https://moodle.org/plugins/?q=category:19%20sort-by:downloads